# Integrating Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm just beginning with programming, but i wanted to know if it's possible to use google docs api to make documents on another site using the google docs text editor?

Is there some sort of way i can put the google docs text editor onto a website so that we can use that for document creation instead of tiny mce?

Basically the functionality needed would be documents created, openly shared, a postable version of it (take html code) -- so it can go on the document display page, and

Of course there would be google login and everything, but i just wanted to see if this would work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899927/how-i-can-embed-google-docs-in-my-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible, sorry.